# Meteor and font-awesome package not working as intended

Tags: meteor, font-awesome

I tried to use font-awesome with meteor by installing the folowing package :

https://atmospherejs.com/natestrauser/font-awesome
https://atmospherejs.com/fortawesome/fontawesome

But with both packages I get the same result, being a box as if the character did not exist :

HTML :

```
<i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-3x pull-left fa-border"></i>
```

Result :

[image: Bug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried that HTML snippet in one of my projects using the official (fortawesome-fontawesome) package and had no issues. There are a slew of potential reasons this could be the case, my first recommendation would be to inspect the element using chrome and look at the CSS. Make sure there's no overriding going on from other CSS files/libraries/packages you may have installed.

Additionally, check your browser console to see if any assets are failing to load.

If you can't seem to find anything out of the ordinary, remove the package `meteor remove fortawesome:fontawesome`, and add it manually by creating an **index.html** file in your project and adding this to it:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed a CSS file overriding font-family, I should have checked that before asking.